# How to show this property of ultrafilter on a set $X$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

Def:

1. Filter: A filter on a set $X$ is a collection $F \subset P(X)$ such that satisfies $a,b,c$
2. Filter basis: A filter on a set $X$ is a collection $F \subset P(X)$ such that satisfies $a,b$
3. Ultrafilter: A proper filter on a set $X$ is an ultrafilter iff it is not properly contained in any other proper filter.

$a.$ $F \neq \emptyset$

$b.$ $A, B \in F$ implies there exists $C\in F$ such that $C \subset A \cap B$

$c.$ $A \in F $ and $A \subset B$ implies $B \in F$

I encountered a proposition which states that

Suppose $\mathcal{U}$ is a filter on $X$, then $\mathcal{U}$ is ultra iff for all $A \in P(X)$, the following condition holds '$A \notin \mathcal{U} \Leftrightarrow \exists B \in  \mathcal{U}$ with $A \cap B =\emptyset$'

Here is my proof, $A \notin \mathcal{U} \Leftrightarrow$ the filter generated by $\mathcal{U} 
\cup \{A\}=P(X) $(Denote is as $F$, it is the smallest filter containing $\mathcal{U} 
\cup \{A\}$) $\Leftrightarrow \emptyset \in F \Leftrightarrow(**Why**) \exists B \in  \mathcal{U}$ with $A \cap B =\emptyset$.

If $\exists B \in  \mathcal{U}$ with $A \cap B =\emptyset$, it is easy to show $\emptyset \in F$, but why the reverse side?

Probably a hint: show $F$ has a filter basis $\{C \cap A; C \in  \mathcal{U}\}$. **How do we come up with the idea to construct a filter basis of this form and magically it generates $F$?**

Comment: What definition of ultrafilter are you using?

Comment: I have added the definitions in the edited version of the question. Hope it makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a nonempty collection $\mathcal A\subseteq P(X),$ the filter generated by $\mathcal A$ is $$ \{A\subseteq X: \exists A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n\in \mathcal A: A_1\cap\ldots \cap A_n \subseteq A\}.$$ (Exercise: check this is indeed a filter, and thus the smallest filter containing $\mathcal A.)$ The filter will be proper iff $\mathcal A$ has the finite intersection property, which means that any finite intersection of sets in $\mathcal A$ is nonempty. Often, "filter" is defined to mean "proper filter", and we just talk about filters generated by collections with the finite intersection property.

So, if you have a proper filter $\mathcal F,$ and there is some $A\notin \mathcal F$ such that $\mathcal F\cup\{A\}$ has the finite intersection property, then it generates a strictly larger proper filter, and thus $\mathcal F$ is not an ultrafilter. A crucial property of filters (often part of the definition, but alas not here, so, exercise) is that they are closed under finite intersections, so $F\cup \{A\}$ having the finite intersection property just means that $A\cap B\ne \emptyset$ for all $B\in \mathcal F.$

So this says that a proper filter $\mathcal U$ is an ultrafilter exactly when $A\in \mathcal U$ iff every $B\in \mathcal U$ has $A\cap B\ne \emptyset,$ which is equivalent to your condition. Another way of putting this is that an ultrafilter is a collection of subsets of $X$ maximal with respect to the finite intersection property.

To make a bit more contact with your hint, note that the collection of all supersets of elements of a filter base are the generated filter and that  for a filter $\mathcal F,$ the filter generated by $\mathcal F\cup \{A\}$ is just the collection of all supersets of sets of the form $A\cap C$ with $C\in \mathcal F.$ The idea is that if none of the sets in the filter base is empty, then the generated filter is proper, so very similar to the reasoning I just gave.

I've personally never had much use for filter bases, and just like to work with collections with the finite intersection property. (I don't know what the name for these are, but they become filter bases once you close them under finite intersections... I guess by correspondence with bases for topologies, that would make them filter-sub-bases?)